# Searching for a C/C++ IDE for OS X that can use a custom gcc installation

Tags: c++, c, xcode, macos, ide

I'm on OS X 10.7.2 "Lion", and I'm developing a C program that has to use some OpenMP **3.0** specific functionalities. Therefore, gcc 4.2.1 is not enough for me, I need **gcc 4.4** or better.

I downloaded MacPorts and easily installed gcc 4.4. Running it from the command line just works fine, and compiles my OpenMP 3.0 C program with no hassle.

But it's quite annoying for me to edit the source in Xcode or TextWrangler and compile it from the command line. So I tried Code::Blocks, which took me 1 hour trying to make it work under OS X, but it crashes anytime for no reason. Then I tried Eclipse, but it sticks on using gcc 4.2.1 even if gcc 4.4 is installed and can be run from the command line. Finally, I tried MonoDevelop, which uses gcc 4.2.1 as well and I just can't see how can I force it to use my favourite gcc version.

What I'm kindly asking you is: is there any decent C/C++ IDE for OS X that I can use which will let **me** to specifiy **what** gcc version to use (just like Code::Blocks under Windows) **without** horrible workarounds and/or breaking gcc 4.2.1 (I need it up and working for Xcode)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse is OK, it can be configured to use any compiler (or several at once or whatever).

> it sticks on using gcc 4.2.1 even if gcc 4.4 is installed and can be run from the command line.

If you want a global setting, then go to `C/C++ / Build / Environment` in your preferences and set its PATH to wherever your favourite GCC is.

---

If you want to be more specific, you can edit a specific project's preferences, for instance:

- `C/C++ Build / Environment` -> `Environment variables to set` (there you can find and customize the final PATH that your compilation will use, per build configuration)
- `C/C++ Build / Settings` -> `GCC C++ Compiler` (and others) - there you can customise the exact binary file of the compiler to execute (defaults to just `g++`), again per build configuration.

This even lets you have a project with 2 build configs, one for GCC 4.2 and one for GCC 4.4 for instance.

Comment: Man, you saved my day. For the records: setting the global Environment 'PATH' variable had no effect at all (in fact, my PATH already pointed to the correct gcc version), I had to manually set the compiler path for the project to /opt/local/bin/gcc

Comment: Interesting. I wonder how your Eclipse picked up "that" gcc in the first place if not from PATH... You didn't have both of them in PATH did you?

Comment: I did have both of them in PATH, but the first element of the PATH variable is /opt/local/bin (I think this has been set by MacPorts), in fact the shell run into Terminal just picks the gcc version under /opt/... For some reason, Eclipse chooses the one in the default path unless I force it to use another executable using the procedure you kindly suggested.

Comment: What if you choose to replace instead of append to the system PATH in the general prefs?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use your gcc with Xcode, without breaking the existing gcc toolchain.  Follow [these instructions](http://belkadan.com/blog/2011/07/Using-Clang-from-SVN-in-Xcode/) (which describe how to use a custom clang build, but the same principle applies to gcc).

Comment: Interesting. I'll look into this even if I succeeded in using gcc 4.4 in Eclipse.